# How to implement Buttons depending on a list?

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, button, ionic3

I want to generate and display as many buttons depending on the number of elements in my list. Can someone tell me how I can implement that?

Currently it is hardcoded like the below code. But often I only have a list with only button 1 and 2. And then I dont need the button 3 and button 4.

Thanks for your help!

```
list=[button1, button2, button3, button4]

<div class="tabs_item_categories">
    <button class="tab_item_category" (click)="button1_active()">
         Button1
    </button>
    <button class="tab_item_category" (click)="button2_active()">
         Button2
    </button>
    <button class="tab_item_category"(click)="button3_active()">
         Button3
    </button>
    <button class="tab_item_category" (click)="button4_active()">
         Button4
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `*ngFor` here is the documentation https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data

Comment: You can do this using iterating through the list and create append buttons accordingly. The one issue is where you want to make the function call on click, where you will need to call a common method and use a switch to call functions accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You iterate with `*ngFor` structural directive in angular:

```
<div class="tabs_item_categories">
    <button class="tab_item_category" 
            *ngFor="let buttonConfig of buttonConfigs" 
            (click)="buttonConfig.onClick()">
        {{buttonConfig.label}}
    </button>
</div>
```

and in your typescript:

```
buttonConfigs = [
    {
        label: 'Button 1',
        onClick: this.doSomethingOnButton1Click
    },
    ...
];
```

`doSomethingOnButton1Click` is lambda in the component.